# Oracle database como filtrar para trazer apenas o ultimo acesso dos usuários

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldeveloper

Estou com problema ao realizar um `select` em um banco de dados Oracle.
preciso filtrar os últimos dos usuários, porem tenho 2 tabelas uma com o cadastro dos usuários e outra com os LOG.
Quando realizo o select ele traz todos os acessos de todos os usuários e eu preciso mostrar somente o ultimo acesso de cada um.

O código que estou utilizando é:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sg.CD_USUARIO AS Código_do_usuario ,
                sg.DCR_USUARIO AS Nome_do_usuário ,
                sg.dcr_login AS Login ,
                sg.data_reg AS Data_do_Registro ,
                u.data_reg AS Data_do_ultimo_acesso
FROM seg_usuario sg
INNER JOIN SEG_LOG_UTILIZACAO u ON sg.cd_usuario = u.cd_usuario
WHERE u.data_reg BETWEEN '01/01/22' AND '09/03/2023' --AND sg.CD_USUARIO = 1
ORDER BY u.data_reg DESC;
```

Comment: Pelo que eu vi da query, parece ok. O problema é que o AND está comentado em sua query, talvez se descomentar o `AND` já resolva o problema.

Answer (score 0):

Se necessita filtrar o resultados para exibir apenas os últimos acessos, basta utilizar comando `FETCH FIRST <N> ROWS ONLY` para limitar a quantidade de resultados (que está disponível a partir do Oracle 12c):

Um exemplo seria o seguinte:

```
SELECT TABLESPACE_NAME FROM USER_TABLESPACES FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

Segue a [documentação do comando](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF01702).

Se quiser mais exemplos de utilização procurar por: `Row Limiting: Examples` no link da documentação acima.